# [API][CORS] Not able to use API despite domain being whitelisted

Tags: rest-api, api, authentication

I'm new to Salesforce, but before asking I've been through docs and can't find a way around it.

I have a Salesforce Developer Edition where I have a user with API privileges, connected app added and CORS set up, but whenever I try to authenticate user from my app (run locally) I get:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token.
>       Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
>       No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
>       Origin 'https://proj.loc:1337' is therefore not allowed access. 
>       The response had HTTP status code 400.

In whitelist I have both https://proj.loc and https://proj.loc:1337 
When using curl to get session ID everything works fine, but not from my js app.

What can be the issue here? Is it possible, that the fact I have a self-signed certificate on my localhost is blocking authentication?

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're trying to authenticate using the CORS request which isn't supported - see [this comment](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html#comment-1860165250) for more details. You should be able to use it for any other API requests though - that will also validate that you whitelisted the correct URLs.

Quoting the relevant text below

> Since our implementation of CORS relies on you whitelisting an origin,
>   we can't use CORS for authentication, since, until you're
>   authenticated, we don't know if your origin is whitelisted for your
>   org, since we don't know which org you're in.